# Win 32: Access Denied when accessing MicrosoftIISv2 namespace in WMI (C#)

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, access-denied

My application is accessing `MicrosoftIIsv2` namespace in local and remote system.
And the error that I am receiving is:

> Win32:Access Denied at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)

Here is the code snippet (Local Host)

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
ObjectQuery query;
ManagementScope scope;
options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
scope = new ManagementScope("root\\MicrosoftIISv2",options);
scope.Connect();
query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM IIsApplicationPool");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();
```

I have been on this problem for way too long. Here are the number of solutions to this problem that I have found on internet.

1. Modifying `connectionOption`:

`options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
 options.EnablePrivileges = true;`

This doesn't seem to solve the problem.

2. Modifying Security privileges in `MicrosoftIISv2` namespace in `wmimgmt.msc` for both local and remote host.
   (Had high hopes with this thing but it didn't change the result)
3. Changed Privileged rights in Access permission and Launch and Activation Permission in dcomcnfg for both host.
   (This neither changed the result)
4. Allow my Visual Studio to run as Administrator.

Voila! Now I can access and retrieve IIS details from my Local Host.
But when this code running(as Administrator) in local computer tries to access `MicrosoftIIsv2` namespace in remote computer with Administrator credential I again get `Win32:Access Denied`.

Can someone please tell me what to do .

Thank you in advance.

Update 1:As per MSDN Win32:Access Denied is received when->

> Requests that use console applications in the Windows System32 directory, such as Cmd.exe, are denied access unless the remote user making the request is an authenticated member of the Administrators group.

This would mean that I have to change ACL of "inetmgr.exe" on each remote computer (which exist in system32 directory) which would be a hectic task to perform.

[Troubleshooting Common IIS Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524996(v=vs.90).aspx#icf).